# How do you set the java version while creating Azure Function App using Terraform?

Tags: java, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

In the Azure Portal I can set the Java Version like follows:
[portal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5p6o.png)

In the terraform config file I can only set the Azure Function version using:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "function-app" {
  name                       = "test"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.service-plan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.storage-account.primary_access_key
  app_settings = {
    FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE         = "readOnly"
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE       = 1
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION    = 2
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME       = "java"
    SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = false
  }
}
```

When deploying the above configuration only the Runtime is set to java, but since the version is not set, my deployments are not working.

The result in portal looks as follows:
[java stack settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzghg.png)

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm doing the suggestion that is accepted but it's not working. The field is still empty. Can you share your configuration? Thanks.

Comment: There is currently a terraform bug outstanding for this https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10229

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `version` argument to set the runtime version associated with the Function App. See [Argument Reference](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html#argument-reference).

[image]

Also, from the docs---[How to target Azure Functions runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version)

> A function app runs on a specific version of the Azure Functions
> runtime. There are three major versions: 1.x, 2.x, and 3.x. By
> default, function apps are created in version 3.x of the runtime.

[image]

In this case, you could add argument `version  =  "~3"` under the  `resource "azurerm_function_app" "function-app""`. It will get your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Nancy Xiong's answer was accepted, because it doesn't answer the question, which is specifically about setting the java version for azure function apps in terraform.
This is how you do it correctly:

```
site_config {
       linux_fx_version = "JAVA|11"    
  }
```

[site_config](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html#site_config) documentation

Comment: Hi, at the time when I added the question, the above answer solved my issue, hence accepted the answer.

Comment: @BalajiArumugam I dont know which version of azurerm provider you were using, but following the accepted answer, doesnt set the java version to 11. you can do it only by Rostos's answer

Answer (score 0):

With the Azure Provider version `>=v2.57.0`, you can set the Java version via the `site_config` property `java_version`.

> java_version - (Optional) Java version hosted by the function app in Azure. Possible values are 1.8, 11.

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "function-app" {
  // ..

  site_config {
    java_version = "11"
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be the way to do it, the only problem is that 1 year after your post still doesn't work.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/17173